# bootstrap4 on ember.js: how do I build this exact top navbar and left side navbar

Tags: ember.js, bootstrap-4

what I would like to do in RED BOX:

[image: Displaying a screenshot to support the question]

hello. obviously I am new and very much a beginner.

I am using ember.js for my application frontend and bootstrap to ease the styling process. I want to build a top fixed menu bar like the picture attached and a left navigation bar with scrolling like the picture attached. maybe because I am new thats why I am unable to use the manuals properly to land me at this point.

if anyone choose to help, need to know 1st that if there are already defined builtin components in ember.js to solve this issue (I am using ember v3.18), I am unable to find any.

2nd, if 1st question answer is no, then how can I build it - or are there any suggestive codes available online for me to learn from?

Comment: Did you had a look at [Ember Bootstrap](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/)? It has a [`<NavBar>` compoonent](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/components/navbars) which provides the functional implementation for the top navigation. The left-side navigation seems to be a combination of an accordion and a bunch of links. Ember Bootstrap also has a [`<Accordion>` component](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/components/accordion). Unless you want to create the links dynamically based on registered route, you can hard-code them using Ember's built-in `<LinkTo>` component.

Comment: for the top menu bar I am trying this " https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/components/navbars " ... but I am getting a blank result ... bootstrap is installed in my folder that I am running the project with.

Comment: Did you installed the Ember Bootstrap addon by running `ember install ember-bootstrap` in your project folder? Did you tried to copy and paste the code from Ember Bootstrap's documentation to make sure that you didn't missed something? Is the HTML markup present in DOM and only styles are missing? Or is it not rendered at all?

Comment: yup everything is installed ... 
it is just not doing anything - not even showing an error ... just giving me a white blank page ...

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without looking at the code. Is the repository public? Or can you create a public reproduction?

Comment: is there any code you can share? what have you tried so far?